# plot specific columns from a text file

Tags: python, plot

If I have a text file, data.txt, which contains many columns, how to call this file by python and plot only chosen two columns?
for example:

```
  10 -22.82215289 0.11s
  12 -22.81978265 0.14s
  15 -22.82359691 0.14s
  20 -22.82464363 0.16s
  25 -22.82615348 0.17s
  30 -22.82641815 0.19s
  35 -22.82649347 0.21s
  40 -22.82655376 0.22s
  50 -22.82661407 0.28s
  60 -22.82663535 0.34s
  70 -22.82664864 0.42s
  80 -22.82665962 0.46s
  90 -22.82666308 0.51s
 100 -22.82666662 0.56s
```

and I need to plot only the first and second columns.
Note the space before the first column.

Eidt
I used the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParamsDefault
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"]=150
plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"]="white"
x, y = np.loadtxt('./calc.dat', delimiter=' ')
plt.plot(x, y, "o-", markersize=5, label='Etot')
plt.xlabel('ecut')
plt.ylabel('Etot')
plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.savefig("fig.png")
```

but I have to modify my data to contain only two columns that I need to plot without any spaces before the first column, as follows

```
 10 -22.82215289  
 12 -22.81978265  
 15 -22.82359691  
 20 -22.82464363  
 25 -22.82615348  
 30 -22.82641815  
 35 -22.82649347  
 40 -22.82655376  
 50 -22.82661407  
 60 -22.82663535  
 70 -22.82664864  
 80 -22.82665962  
 90 -22.82666308  
100 -22.82666662
```

So, how to modify the code so that I do not have to modify the data every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DataFrame from from a text file using pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which can simplify future processing of the data, besides plotting it.

In this case, the tricky part are the whitespaces, that can be managed by setting the optional parameter `sep` to `'\s+'`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+', header=None, names=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
>>>df
```

| index | foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | -22.82215289 | 0.11s |
| 1 | 12 | -22.81978265 | 0.14s |
| 2 | 15 | -22.82359691 | 0.14s |
| 3 | 20 | -22.82464363 | 0.16s |
| 4 | 25 | -22.82615348 | 0.17s |
| 5 | 30 | -22.82641815 | 0.19s |
| 6 | 35 | -22.82649347 | 0.21s |
| 7 | 40 | -22.82655376 | 0.22s |
| 8 | 50 | -22.82661407 | 0.28s |
| 9 | 60 | -22.82663535 | 0.34s |
| 10 | 70 | -22.82664864 | 0.42s |
| 11 | 80 | -22.82665962 | 0.46s |
| 12 | 90 | -22.82666308 | 0.51s |
| 13 | 100 | -22.82666662 | 0.56s |

And the just your code:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"]=150
plt.rcParams["figure.facecolor"]="white"
plt.plot(df['foo'], df['bar'], "o-", markersize=5, label='Etot')
plt.xlabel('ecut')
plt.ylabel('Etot')
plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.savefig("fig.png")
```

[image]

I set the names of the columns to arbitrary strings. You can avoid that, and just refer to the columns as `df[0], df[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could first read your file `data.txt` and preprocess it by stripping the whitespaces on the left of each line, save the preprocessed data to `data_processed.txt`, then load it with `pd.read_csv` and then plot the two columns of choice `col1` and `col2` against each other with `plt.plot`, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = """  10 -22.82215289 0.11s
  12 -22.81978265 0.14s
  15 -22.82359691 0.14s
  20 -22.82464363 0.16s
  25 -22.82615348 0.17s
  30 -22.82641815 0.19s
  35 -22.82649347 0.21s
  40 -22.82655376 0.22s
  50 -22.82661407 0.28s
  60 -22.82663535 0.34s
  70 -22.82664864 0.42s
  80 -22.82665962 0.46s
  90 -22.82666308 0.51s
 100 -22.82666662 0.56s"""


with open ('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)

with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

data_processed = '\n'.join([l.lstrip() for l in data.split('\n')])

with open ('data_processed.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data_processed)

df = pd.read_csv('data_processed.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
col1 = 0
col2 = 1
plt.plot(df[col1], df[col2]);
```

[image: plot]